# Setting ratio of requests when load testing in SoapUI (Free Version)

Tags: soapui

I am trying to load test a web service containing multiple web methods. Some web service methods are called more than others so I am trying to simulate a realistic load (as much as possible).

Example:

1 request to web method x

5 requests to web method y

24 requests to web method z

Ideally I would like it to start out like this then increase the magnitude of the requests based on the above ratio's.

Is their anyway to do this in the free version of SoapUI?

I have thought about adding a delay to each request but the delay facility provided delays the whole test case, not just that request.

It seems that SoapUI just pushes out as many requests as possible of each web service method which is not helpful at all as some requests are barely called and cause a lot of processing to be done on the server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, you can do it by some groovy scripting.
For instance, you could put a groovy script that will run you request n-th times.
To run the test step from test_suite check this code:

```
 import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestRunner.Status
    def tc = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["TestSuite_Name"].testCases["Test_Case_Name"]
    tc.setPropertyValue("Property_Name", value)
    def runner = tc.run( null, false )
    log.info "Status: $runner.status, time taken for TestCase was: $runner.timeTaken ms"
    // assert that it didn't fail
    assert runner.status != Status.FAILED : runner.reason
```

In your case, you can add such code and applyloop to run test steps as well.
Finally, for delays can you smth like this:

```
random = new Random()
randomNum = random.nextInt(100)+1
log.info(randomNum)
if ( randomNum > 70 )  {
     testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName( "Test_Step_Name" ).disabled = true
}
else {
     testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName( "Test_Step_Name" ).disabled = false
}
```

i.e. turn_off the request for some time